# Laravel sort by descending or ascending with pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to perform a sort by ascending or descending together with pagination

```
  return \App\User:: paginate($request->per_page);
```

how do i add the sort by so something like this

```
return \App\User:: paginate($request->per_page)-sortBy(
    $request->sort_field, $request->sort_order
  );
```

bur the above fails where

```
$request->sort_order //asc or desc
```

the above returns an error of

```
"asort() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given"
```

Comment: possible duplicates of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429427/laravel-eloquent-ordering-results-of-all

Comment: @teeyo your duplicate reference throws an error

Comment: Check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

```
User::orderBy($request->sort_field, $request->sort_order)->paginate($request->per_page);
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/combining-paginate-with-orderby

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the syntax in where you may enter the order (DESC or ASC) in the Laravel docs, Try this :

```
if ($request->sort_order == 'asc') {
   return \App\User::paginate($request->per_page)->sortBy($request->sort_field); 
}
return \App\User::paginate($request->per_page)->sortByDesc($request->sort_field);
```

Read more in the docs : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby

Comment: update -sortBy to ->sortBy otherwise the above throws an error

Comment: Now it works thanks, but Ron answer above provides a cleaner syntax

Comment: The most important that you got your answer, that's what SO is about ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using Eloquent you can sort and paginate your data quickly and easily.

For example, I want to sort all users that exist in the user table.

```
//---Sort Ascending
$users = User::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->Paginate(10);
//---Sort Descending
$users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->Paginate(10);
```