# Sort By highest ID in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to sort posts by highest id :/. Currently, the code sorts them by the lowest ID.

```
$posts->sortBy('id');
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent: Ordering results of all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429427/laravel-eloquent-ordering-results-of-all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$posts->sortByDesc('id');
```

Source: [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortbydesc)

Comment: Wow! Thanks, really thanks! :O It's working, really, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For sorting by highest id use orderBy in Laravel, for example if you want to sort all your projects:

```
$projects = Project::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```